# timezone in xcode project

Tags: ios, calendar, timezone, nscalendar

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
                [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
                NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:ExamTime];

                 NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
 NSDateFormatter *timeformater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [timeformater setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
            [timeformater setDateFormat:@"EEEE-dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm a"];
                NSString *strSelectedDate= [timeformater stringFromDate:newDate];
```

i writing this code and i want to change the timezone for time the problem not rsolving please help me and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert your date to **NSDateComponents** first. Just create **NSDateFormatter**, setup it with format and time zone and convert date to string. To set time zone to GMT (+0000), create it like this:

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

So the overall code will look like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *timeformater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeformater setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
[timeformater setTimeZone:timeZone];
[timeformater setDateFormat:@"EEEE-dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSString *strSelectedDate= [timeformater stringFromDate:ExamTime];
```

Comment: ok but i want timezone in beirut/lebanon and a set this method at timezone "UTC" when change this this string to NSDate the time is changed minus 4 hours what i can do please ,i want convert this string to date to use in my notification ,thanks

Comment: Just configure your NSDateFormatter with correct time zone. For your case time zone is setup like this: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EET"].

Answer (score -1):

I think there is something wrong with the timezone name which you want to set.You can get all the time zone by :

```
NSArray *timeZoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
```

then you can set the timezone as :

```
NSCalendar *gregorian=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"]];
NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[timeZoneComps setHour:16];
//specify whatever day, month, and year is appropriate
NSDate *date=[gregorian dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps];
```

You can get more details at :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html

Comment: i use this code but the time is minus one hours, my timzone is in beyrouth/lebanon how can resolve this problem and thanks